# Javascript call functions from html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a string like this

```
var methodString =  "<script>
var a;
var b;

function func1(v1, v2)
{
 ..///DO random stuff
}
</script>";
```

I then attach this code to the end of the body after a button click somewhere on the page

```
 $(body).append(methodString);
```

**How do I call this new function that i just appended**

```
$("button1").click(function() { func1(a,b); }); //This doesn't seem to recognize the new method.
```

Comment: is your question description have any relevance with your question title???

Comment: umm... use an event listener?

Comment: try to make your question more understandable ...

Comment: I would for sure change `</script>` to `<\/script>` if the string appears inside script tags. And change the line endings to \ to allow the newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple HTML

```
<button onclick="func1(a,b);">Click me</button>
```

With jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myButton').click(function(){
        func1(a,b);
    });
</script>
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Why are you promoting inline js? Javascript isn't meant to be inline with HTML.

Comment: @Nile what's the problem with inline JS? Even SO uses inline javascript. He asked, I've answered. Added jQuery answer also .. satisfied?

Comment: Upvoted to make it even, it isn't the job to specify what is right based on opinion - both are functionally correct and doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @MihaiIorga..it says function is not defined

Comment: @MihaiIorga You can't reason with bad practice by saying "even SO does it."